# Need a way to extract the date and time parameters from this data-like text Aug 14 2023 11:36AM to be recognized as actual date

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

In excel I'm looking for an approach to extract the date and time parameters from this data-like text string Aug 14 2023 11:36AM and convert it into a different format such as 8/14/2023 11:36AM.

I've read through a number of approaches others have asked but and made an attempt to parse the text and insert a comma using the formula

```
=CONCAT(LEFT(TRIM(A2),3), " ", MID(A2,5,2), ","," ", MID(A2,8,4))
```

which pulls out Aug 14, 2023. Normally when this is typed in directly into an Excel table cell it will convert to the actual date format. However, it does not even when I change the fields data type to shortdate. Ultimately, I want to capture the entire time and date and make it recognize like an actual date. Is there a special function that will allow this?

(I've often reformatted the date using `=Text(A1, "yyyy-mm-dd")` for 8/14/2023 however I have not seen any single function that will convert this to a date but maybe there is).

Comment: Try: `=LET(a, RIGHT(A1,2), SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",", ",2),a," "&a)+0)` and format cells as per your preference. The output will be a number since as we all date and times are stored as number and fractions of a day in excel, hence for the said date and time, it will show you as `45152.48333` which you need to format as from `Format Cells` --> `Category` --> `Date` --> select the 13th sample which will return in display as `8/14/2023 11:36 AM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like I have commented above, this would work with `MS365` on present channel.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=LET(a, RIGHT(A1,2), SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",", ",2),a," "&a)+0)
```

---

The above formula needs to fill down or if you want a single dynamic array formula, then

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C1</kbd>

```
=MAP(A1:A3,LAMBDA(x,SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(x," ",", ",2),RIGHT(x,2)," "&RIGHT(x,2))+0))
```

---

**Notes:** The output will be a number (if the output cells are not priorly formatted) since as we all know date and times are stored as number and fractions of a day in excel, hence for the said date and time, it will show you as `45152.48333` which you need to format as from <kbd>Format Cells</kbd> --> <kbd>Category</kbd> --> <kbd>Date</kbd> --> select the `13th` sample which will return in display as `8/14/2023 11:36 AM`

---

Or, if you only need the day, then this is suffice.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=TEXTBEFORE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A3," ",", ",2)," ",-1)+0
```

---

Or, only the time then,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTAFTER(A1," ",3),RIGHT(A1,2)," "&RIGHT(A1,2))/1
```

---

Update By OP in comments:

> *Thank you. Both worked. How do you handle these like Aug 3 2023 9:03AM*
> *where the day is single digit? I know how to pad day value like this*
> *=IF(LEN(TRIM(MID(A2,5,2)))*<*2,CONCAT("0",TRIM(MID(A2,5,2))),TRIM(MID(A2,5,2)))*
> *but how would those formulas work to handle either single or double*
> *digit day values?*

---

The given formula the first one will still work even if it is single digit or double digit, as we are not looking for the digits here, but we are looking for the second delimiter which is a space on which we are segregating the <kbd>month day, year</kbd> format which eventually is considers and turns into a valid date form in excel. Please refer the following screenshot where in it shows it works even when the date is a single digit with the same formula.

[image]

---

To validate my answer, if you click the date format and check the 12th sample, you will find the format which excel understands reciprocates to as a date that is it actually reads the number that is how dates are stored in excel. Although this formatting and formula varies with regional settings as well excel versions, the above formula will work without any issues in `MS365` or `Excel 2021` for other versions, we need to scrap the <kbd>LET()</kbd> function and use the repeated formulas to make it work, basically it remains same.

[image]

---

Comment: Thank you. Both worked. How do you handle these like Aug  3 2023  9:03AM where the day is single digit? I know how to pad day value like this =IF(LEN(TRIM(MID(A2,5,2)))<2,CONCAT("0",TRIM(MID(A2,5,2))),TRIM(MID(A2,5,2))) but how would those formulas work to handle either single or double digit day values?

Comment: @NewJackSwing4Ever yes, i have updated, and it even works with single digit as well, there is no change. Also if the answer helps you to resolve kindly ensure to accept the same so it helps someone in the future.

Comment: Thank you soo much!!! You are awesome!! I will accept 1000%! The reason for the delayed response is it still wasn't working until I discovered the tool I used to export for some reason put extra an space between the month and day (Aug and 3) for all other single digit dates but did not put that extra space for the double digit dates and I use a formula =SUBSTITUTE(A4,"  "," ") to fix those instances before applying either of the other formulas. Not easy to spot immediately in case someone else experiences the same issue.

Comment: @NewJackSwing4Ever ah cool, you could have shared me an excel workbook link using one drive, i could have researched more and find out specifically what was the issue, few things cant be detected from the post itself for that it specifically needs the workbook, glad at last you made it to work. Also this is the most simplest way to resolve, the whole credit goes to **`Microsoft Team`**

Comment: Ah, good point on sharing the file. For the future I'll have to look more into using how to share private on stackoverflow via ondrive, googledrive or dropbox here. Haven't done so yet. Thanks for the suggestion.